# How can I apply a function to sequential subsets of data in R?

Tags: r, sapply

In general, suppose I want to apply a function `foo` to the first k points of a dataset of size N, with k ranging from 1 to N.

My way of accomplishing this currently is, for example,

```
X = runif(50000)
foo = function(Y){sum(Y)}
sapply(1:length(X), function(k){foo(X[1:k])})
```

But this seems hacky and inefficient. Using

```
cumsum(X)
```

is much faster; taking 0.01s instead of 18s for the original method. Is there a less hacky and more efficient way of doing this for a generic `foo`?

Comment: `cumsum` is written entirely in C I believe, while you have an overhead of having to call the compiled `sum` code `length(X)` times from within R. I very possibly am wrong, but I can't think of a way to make this generically faster without resorting to compiled code of some type - e.g. through Rcpp. I'd wait for a more expert opinion than mine though.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that it's not really reasonable to expect this kind of performance out of a generic `foo` because `cumsum` takes advantage of the fact that the partial sums can be calculated iteratively. So maybe I shouldn't expect significant performance benefits out of a different method, but I still wonder if there is a better practice for this situation.